# PyGTKDeprecationWarning: What am I missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

My code works just fine, but I get this warning in the terminal when I run the script. What am I missing?

```
abc.py:10: PyGTKDeprecationWarning: Using positional arguments with the GObject constructor has been deprecated. Please specify keyword(s) for "label" or use a class specific constructor. See: https://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject/InitializerDeprecations
actor_act = Gtk.Button("Click Here")
```

Name of the script: *abc.py*

Actual code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def actor(button):
    print('Simple Button')

boxy = Gtk.Window(title="Hello")
boxy.set_default_size(500,500)
actor_act = Gtk.Button("Click Here")
boxy.add(actor_act)

actor_act.connect("clicked", actor)
boxy.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

boxy.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: try : Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Click Here")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Gtk.Button:
>
> class: **new_with_label (label)**
>
> Creates a GtkButton widget with a GtkLabel child containing the given
> text.
>
> Parameters:  label #The text you want the GtkLabel to hold.
>
> Returns: The newly created GtkButton widget.

```
Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Click Here")
```